# RDD of List String convert to Row

Tags: list, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I'm trying to convert an RDD that has a fixed size lists of strings (a result of parsing CSV file) into and RDD of Rows.  This is so I can turn it into a dataframe, because I need it into a dataframe to write to parquet.  Anyway the only part I need help with is the converting of Rdd from list of strings to Row.

The RDD variable name is RDD

Comment: And what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Ok I converted to Row I used val RowRDD = RDD.map(r => Row.fromSeq(r))

Comment: Does this change anything then ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
val RowRDD = RDD.map(r => Row.fromSeq(r))
```