# toDF() not handling RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, row, rdd

I have an RDD of Rows called RowRDD.  I am simply trying to convert into DataFrame.  From the examples I have seen on the internet from various places, I am seeing that I shoudl be trying RowRDD.toDF()  I am getting the error :

`value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't work because `Row` is not a `Product` type and `createDataFrame` with as single `RDD` argument is defined only for `RDD[A]` where `A <: Product`.

If you want to use `RDD[Row]` you have to provide a schema as the second argument. If you think about it is should be obvious. `Row` is just just a container of `Any` and as such it doesn't provide enough information for schema inference.

Assuming this is the same `RDD` as defined in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35441126/1560062) then schema is easy to generate:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RD

val rowRdd: RDD[Row] = ???
val schema = StructType(
  (1 to rowRdd.first.size).map(i => StructField(s"_$i", StringType, false))
)

val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRdd, schema)
```